# How to make Django Admin TabularInline sortable by custom field?

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django Admin, it's easy to create a custom field on the model list page, e.g.:

```
    @admin.register(MyModel)
    class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        list_display = ('id', 'field1', 'field2', 'custom_field3')

        def custom_field3(self, obj):
            return obj.get_custom_field3_display()
        custom_field3.short_description = 'Custom Field 3'
        custom_field3.admin_order_field = 'field3'  # makes column header sortable
```

MyModel.field3 will be used to sort the now clickable "Custom Field 3" column header on the model list page.

How can I achieve the same on an inline model?  I can easily define a custom field in the same way, but the `admin_order_field` line doesn't achieve the same result:

```
    class MyModelInline(admin.TabularInline):
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'field1', 'field2', 'custom_field3')

        def custom_field3(self, obj):
            return obj.get_custom_field3_display()
        custom_field3.short_description = 'Custom Field 3'
        custom_field3.admin_order_field = 'field3'  # doesn't seem to have any effect
```

Comment: the `sort` or **`order_by(...)`** is something that executed in the Database level. You may need to create an *annotated field* and then apply `.filter(...)` over *annotated field*

Comment: @ArakkalAbu, that would still have to be connected to the column header and seems like a lot of additional work, both back-end and front-end.  I'm hoping for an easier solution, not too far from my working MyModelAdmin example.